# Support errors with lifetimes to have a source

Tags: error-handling, rust

I have the following 3 errors, `AError`, `BError` and `CError`, where `CError` contains a borrowed string from some input, and `AError` is composed from either `BError` or `CError`, and thus has a lifetime too.

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum AError<'a> {
    B(BError),
    C(CError<'a>),
}

impl<'a> fmt::Display for AError<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "AError")
    }
}

impl<'a> Error for AError<'a> {
    fn source(&self) -> Option<&(dyn Error + 'static)> {
        match self {
            AError::B(err) => Some(err),
            AError::C(_) => None,        // If I try to use `C(err) => Some(err)` it errors
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct BError;

impl fmt::Display for BError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "BError")
    }
}

impl Error for BError {}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct CError<'a> {
    c: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> fmt::Display for CError<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "CError: {}", self.c)
    }
}

impl<'a> Error for CError<'a> {}
```

If I try to make `A` return `C` as a source error, I get the following error:

```rust
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:18:15
   |
18 |         match self {
   |               ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 16:6...
  --> src/lib.rs:16:6
   |
16 | impl<'a> Error for AError<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/lib.rs:18:15
   |
18 |         match self {
   |               ^^^^
   = note: expected `&AError<'_>`
              found `&AError<'a>`
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/lib.rs:18:9
   |
18 | /         match self {
19 | |             AError::B(err) => Some(err),
20 | |             AError::C(err) => Some(err),
21 | |         }
   | |_________^
   = note: expected `Option<&(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>`
              found `Option<&dyn std::error::Error>`
```

Which makes sense as `source` is declared with `fn source(&self) -> Option<&(dyn Error + 'static)>`.

I understand in order to be able to downcast, you must have a static reference, but all I want to do with it is print a backtrace of errors using `source` as such:

```rust
pub fn fmt_err(err: &dyn Error, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
    writeln!(f, "{}", err)?;

    if let Some(source) = err.source() {
        fmt_err(source, f)?;
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

which doesn't require downcasting, simply uses the fact that `fmt::Display` is a super-trait of `Error`.

**How can I make my errors with lifetimes support this type of usecase?**

I know `Error::cause` exists, but it is deprecated and likely not intended for this use case and popular error deriving libraries (such as `thiserror`) likely don't implement it either, so I have to make do with `source` as my only way of getting an underlying error.

Is my only option to make my own trait and implement it for any errors with lifetimes?

Comment: "fmt::Display is a super-trait of Error"  - actually, fmt::Display is not a super trait of Error. It says that a type, which implements an Error must also implement a Display. It is a nuance but it's sometimes important.

Comment: @lpiepiora I thought that was the very definition of a super trait, no? As explained here https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/supertraits.html